# How to make Graphicstate Image appear on top and not in the background

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm working on a pdf project using Apache PDFBox, it displays a list of transactions that extends to new pages once the current page is filled, for each transaction that is displayed purple color is used to create the row and when the next is displayed white color creates the row and so on. I want to place a stamp at the bottom of each page which I have done, I set the stamp image using graphics state to increase and decrease the opacity of the image, however, the image appears under the transaction row like a watermark but I want in to appear ontop. How to can I achieve that? Below is my code

```
JsonArray transactionList = SampleDataGenerator
                    .generateSampleData()
                    .getJsonObject("data")
                    .getJsonArray("transactionList");
            for (int i = 0; i < transactionList.size(); i++) {
                JsonObject transaction = transactionList.getJsonObject(i);

PDPageContentStream newPagesContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);

                if (dataYPosition - rowHeight < margin) {
                    page = new PDPage();
                    document.addPage(page);
                    dataYPosition = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - 130f; // Adjust newPage rowHeight
                    PdfImageDrawer.drawColumnHeader(newPagesContentStream, HELVETICA, columnXPosition, columnYPosition + 85f);
                    PdfImageDrawer.drawLogo(document, newPagesContentStream);
                }

                
                

                List<String> transactionValues = generateTransactionRow.doGenerateRow(transaction);
                for (String dataValues : transactionValues) {
                    newPagesContentStream.setNonStrokingColor(i % 2 == 0 ? new Color(229, 229, 255) : Color.WHITE);
                    newPagesContentStream.addRect(dataXPosition - 35f, dataYPosition, tableWidth, rectangleHeight);
                    newPagesContentStream.fill();
                    newPagesContentStream.setNonStrokingColor( new Color(112, 112, 112));

                    newPagesContentStream.beginText();
                    newPagesContentStream.setFont(HELVETICA, 6.5f);
                    newPagesContentStream.newLineAtOffset(dataXPosition, dataYPosition + 25f);
                    newPagesContentStream.showText(dataValues);
                    newPagesContentStream.endText();
                    dataXPosition += 100f;
                }
                dataXPosition += -600f;
                dataYPosition -= rowHeight;

                contentStream.saveGraphicsState();
                PdfImageDrawer.drawTextStampInputStream(newPagesContentStream, stampImage);
                newPagesContentStream.close();
            }

//FOOTER
            PdfImageDrawer.drawTextStampInputStream(contentStream, stampImage);

            contentStream.close();
```

drawTextStampInputStream

```
public static void drawTextStampInputStream(PDPageContentStream contentStream, PDImageXObject stampImage) throws IOException {
        String text1 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String text2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String text3 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

//        contentStream.saveGraphicsState();

        PDType1Font HELVETICA = new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.HELVETICA);
        PDExtendedGraphicsState textGraphicsState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
        textGraphicsState.setNonStrokingAlphaConstant(0.050f);
        contentStream.setGraphicsStateParameters(textGraphicsState);

        PdfTextWriter.doWrite(contentStream, HELVETICA, 8f,
                (700f) / 3f, 60f, 0, text1);
        PdfTextWriter.doWrite(contentStream, HELVETICA, 8f,
                140f, 50f, 0, text2);
        PdfTextWriter.doWrite(contentStream, HELVETICA, 8f,
                190f, 40f, 0, text3);


        PDExtendedGraphicsState graphicsState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
        graphicsState.setNonStrokingAlphaConstant(0.10f);
        contentStream.setGraphicsStateParameters(graphicsState);
        contentStream.drawImage(stampImage, 480F, 10f,
                stampImage.getWidth() / 4F,
                stampImage.getHeight() / 4F);
        contentStream.restoreGraphicsState();

    }
```

Comment: *"the image appears under the transaction row like a watermark but I want in to appear ontop."* - can you share images illustrating what you want and what you get?

Comment: Contains some data I can't share with the public. The stamp image appears as it should but the part where it crosses the transaction row, that part becomes a blur and is in the background of the column. It's still visible but not as the other parts of the image.

Comment: Without an illustration I can only guess. Perhaps you shouldn't use alpha transparency but instead blend mode Multiply...

Comment: Blendmode didn't give the desired opacity, I just added an image, will take it down soon. I hope you get the bug.. thanks

Comment: Ok, I see your image. Is that how it looks like now? Or is it how you want it to look like?

Comment: That's how it looks like now, I want the whole stamp to appear like the covered part. So it will be on top of the column rows and not in the background

Comment: *"I want the whole stamp to appear like the covered part. "* - What did you do differently there to get that appearance? Why not doing the same for the whole stamp?

Comment: In the for loop where this                   newPagesContentStream.setNonStrokingColor(i % 2 == 0 ? new Color(229, 229, 255) : Color. WHITE); is set, at that point where the stamp is blurred the white color is there

Comment: Well, considering that you use an alpha value of 0.1, it is very plausible that the stamp only is there faintly. Why do you use transparency here at all if you want the stamp to clearly appear on top?

Comment: Well I'm trying to work based on the design and it's light, even when I increase the the value or use blend mode that part is still not even

Comment: You may want to try the blend mode Darken.

Comment: One more question, why do you want to apply global transparency here at all? If you want the stamp on top, you simply don't want global transparency there.

Comment: blend mode Darken fixed it, thanks a lot

Comment: I'll make that an actual answer then (instead of a mere comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option for having a rubber stamp bitmap image on top with the background visible where the rubber stamp does not color, is to have those regions of the bitmap image itself transparent. Then you don't need to apply some global graphics state transparency, the transparency of the stamp image will do the job.

If you cannot make sure that the stamp bitmap image is transparent where it should be but instead fairly white, you can try to achieve a similar effect using global graphics state transparency.

Constant alpha transparency which you tried in your code, is not giving the desired result, either the rubber stamp itself becomes to faint or the empty are in-between is not transparent enough.

But PDF supports a much richer transparency model, there in particular are the different blend modes. For a task like yours the blend modes **Darken** and **Multiply** work best.